# how to set default resolution for web page

Tags: css, html

This is my website http://kaybs.in/Medical/index.html, my problem is how to set a default resolution for this webpage to look same in all monitors,how to fix the `css` ?

Answer (score 1):

maybe it help you

```
body {
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your website try reading media queries and set your image(carousel) for a max-width so it doesn't get stretched.

Try reading this:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

http://mediaqueri.es/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag